# Activity indicator on UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, title, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a custom button and I need to show an activity indicator instead of the title label after I  tap  the button. To hide titleLabel I use

```
self.titleLabel.layer.opacity = 0.0f;
```

In the method, where indicator starts animating

```
- (void)startAnimating {
[self bringSubviewToFront: self.spinner];
self.titleLabel.layer.opacity = 0.0f;
[self.spinner startAnimating];

self.titleLabel.layer.opacity = ([self isAnimating]) ? 0.0f : 1.0f;
[self setNeedsDisplay];
```

}

It works, but not for a long tap. When I use a long tap, the title label is not hidden, an activity indicator appears above the title. I tried to set the color for the title in "startAnimating", it works, but I think it is not a good solution. 
If somebody could help, it would be really appreciated:)

Comment: why dont you use `self.titleLabel.hidden = true`?

Comment: It does not work too. It was the first i'd tried to do

Answer (score 4):

Try this(swift) :

```
@IBOutlet var buttonTap: UIButton!
var indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()

@IBAction func buttonTap(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    buttonTap.setTitle("", for: .normal)
    indicator.center = buttonTap.center
    indicator.color = UIColor.black
    indicator.startAnimating()
}
```